# When to use Underscore.js vs Knockout.js for JS templating in M2?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, underscorejs

I see that core M2 uses both Underscore.js and Knockout.js, although it looks like M2 core has extended base Knockout and added some new functionality to it.

If I am building something that binds data from a JSON object retrieved through an AJAX call, and updating the site based on the data, which library should I use for templating and why?